# How to ask a miner for help?

Tags: transaction-fees

after reading on, and checking my transaction, it think i;ve paid far too little for my transaction - This was not intentional - honest mistake as it was my first time of doing this...

how can i get this pushed through, i don;t mind giving the miner more transaction money to help.

thanks - tim

Comment: Here you go https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_accelerator

Comment: confirmtx.com, I'd suggest

Comment: thanks guys - just used that confirmtx.com - lets see- thanks :)